# How to return an array of objects in Json format from MySQL using php prepared-statement

Tags: php, mysql, json, phpmyadmin, prepared-statement

I'm trying to write a function in php that will allow me to return an array of objects (in my case the objects are the rows in my database(MySQL) from phpMyAdmin) into a Json format.

Here is my function:

```
public function getAllCases()
    {

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM mycase ");
        $stmt->execute();
        $arr = []
        $result = $stmt->get_result();

        while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
            $arr[] = $row;
        }

        return $arr;
    }
```

I couldn't find anything else online and this function is not working.
For example if my table has 4 rows, I want to be able to get 4 objects and each one of those 4 objects should represent a row from the table and it's columns.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So you want a JSON string returned..?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? What happens instead on executing that code?

Comment: phpMyAdmin is a MySQL administration tool written in PHP, it is not a database itself. You should use this tag for problems related to using this tool and not for general query problems. Are you sure that this question should be tagged with phpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to convert array to JSON and vice versa.

```
return json_encode($arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert a php array into json , Use json_encode() function. And in your code, You mixed up Normal and Prepared Statements.

```
public function getAllCases()
{
    $data = array();
    $result = $this->conn->query("SELECT * FROM `mycase`");
    $num_rows = $result->num_rows;
    if ($num_rows  > 0) {                           
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $data[] = $row; 
        }
     }
    return json_encode($data);
}
```